# Why does "1 in (True, None)" evaluate True in python?

Tags: python

I wanted to test whether a value was either `True` or `None` and thought the pythonic way of writing this conditions was `val in (True, None)`.

Turns out, if `val = 1` this evaluates to True.

The only way I could find was the clumsy `val is True or val is None`.

What is the deeper reason that `1 in (True, None)` evaluates to `True`? Is there a more compact way of writing the above condition?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I suggest leaning towards designs where you don't have to distinguish between `val` being `1`, and `val` being `True`. I often find it beneficial to restrict a variable to a single type - if I only ever assign bools to it, I know it will never be 1; and if I only ever assign ints to it, I know it will never be True. There's no chance for ambiguity, that way.

Comment: @Kevin "if I only ever assign bools to it"-- bools *are* ints in python (`isinstance(True, int)`)

Comment: @Kevin This is an interface to a c library. Hence the somewhat unusual use case.

Comment: Strange, I would expect C libraries to have _stricter_ type requirements than Python's. Unless it's returning a void pointer, I suppose.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Please reopen. The referenced answers only answer the first part of my question. Whether the condition can be written more compactly is not. Do you want me to reformulate to limit the scope of the question to the second part?

Comment: using `is` is fine, you could alternatively use `isinstance(1, (bool, type(None)))` (also true for `False`) but i prefer using `is`-- i'll re-open anyway

Answer (score 1):

`True` is `bool` which is inherits from integer and is equal to `1` (but is not the exact same as `1`).

```py
help(bool)
```

Output:

```
class bool(int)
 |  bool(x) -> bool
 |
 |  Returns True when the argument x is true, False otherwise.
 |  The builtins True and False are the only two instances of the class bool.
 |  The class bool is a subclass of the class int, and cannot be subclassed.
 |
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      bool
 |      int
 |      object
```

But because `True` inherits from `int`, we should be able to do everything with a `bool` that we can with an `int`!

```py
print(5 + True) # > 6
print(17 - False) # > 17
print(15//True) # > 15
print(10/False) # > raises ZeroDivisionError since False "=" 0
```

To answer your *main* question however, which is explaining why `1 in (True, None)` evaluates to `True` is because the `in` operator works by checking `equality` (with `==`) and not object identity (with `is`). The `None` in your statement has nothing to do with it; it could be any object and your statement would still evaluate to `True`.

```py
print(1 == True) # > True
print(1 is True) # > False
```

*`True` is `1` but with a little extra fluff added to it from the `bool` methods*

I think a pythonic way of achieving what you're after is to check if the object's identity is contained in the list (which is what you suggested, but we can generalize it a bit)

```py
id(1) in [id(x) for x in [True, None]] # > False
```

Essentially this is just a stronger version of the `in` operator. We can write it as a function:

```py
def stronger_in(val, it):
    return id(val) in [id(_) for _ in it]
print(stronger_in(1, (True, None)) # > False
```